# On threads and object creation

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say you have a class `MyClass` that has a constructor

```
public Myclass(SomeObject o)
```

`Myclass`, additionally has a method `public void doSomethingCleverWith(String s)`

I'd like for `MyClass` to be executed as a `Thread`, so I

```
Thread t = new Thread(new MyClass(SomeObject));
```

When executing this thread, however `run`, will need to call `doSomethingCleverWith(String)`. run, however (as i understand it) does not take in any parameters.

How would you recommend i handle this? Should String s be a part of a `MyClass`'s constructor? Can i somehow do something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't execute an *object* on a thread - you execute *code* on a thread... the code specified by the `run()` method of the runnable that you pass in to the `Thread` constructor, assuming you're doing it that way.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you *probably* need to pass the extra information (the string) to the constructor of `MyClass`... or execute it in a different way, such as:

```
final MyClass tmp = new MyClass(SomeObject));
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        tmp.doSomethingCleverWithString(someValueHere);
    }
});
```

If you clarify what you're trying to achieve, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: he knows to have his Object implement `Runnable`, he's trying to figure out how to inject a `String` into that object prior to passing it to the `Thread` constructor.

Comment: @BrianRoach: That's why I've given two different approaches - either changing the constructor to `MyClass`, or using an anonymous inner type as per my sample code. But I think it's always worth correcting the idea that an *object* runs in a thread.

Answer (score 1):

Given the above, I would make `MyClass` implement `Runnable`, and take `SomeObject` as a construction parameter to populate a field.

Your implementation of `run()` would then invoke your class using that field as a parameter.

Don't forget to call `start()` on the `Thread` btw., and not `run()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) to ensure your `MyClass` objects is constructed correctly, or simple dependency injection as you suspect (passing the `String` to the `MyClass` constructor).

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the intended lifecycle of MyClass.  If you have a situation where MyClass(SomeObject) is supposed to act on multiple different Strings over the course of its life, then you can avoid additional object construction by handing String instances to it through some method instead of in the constructor.

If MyClass(SomeObject) is only ever going to act on one String, then you should pass the String in during construction (or you could still pass it via another method before starting MyClass if the creation of MyClass should be separate from its use).

Assuming you want multiple Strings to be processed per MyClass instance, and the reason for the separate thread is simply for asynchronous processing, then I would use a BlockingQueue implementation to have a single thread that processes requests asynchronously (using a separate AsyncProcessor that wraps my existing synchronous processor).  Eg:

```
public interface StringProcessor
{
  public void processString(String string);
}

public class AsyncProcessor implements StringProcessor
{
  private final ArrayBlockingQueue<String> queue;
  private final StringProcessor immediateProcessor;

  private AsyncProcessor(StringProcessor immediateProcessor, int maxQueue)
  {
    this.queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue(maxQueue);
    this.immediateProcessor = immediateProcessor;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ProcessingTask());
    thread.start();
  }

  // Add string to queue for asynchronous processing later.
  public void processString(String string)
  {
    queue.offer(string);
    // Handle / log insert failure (queue full, maybe throw an Exception)
  }

  private class ProcessingTask implements Runnable
  {

    public volatile boolean running = true;

    public void run()
    {
      while(running)
      {
        // Probably need to deal with InterruptedException here...
        immediateProcessor.processString(queue.take());
      }
    }
  }
}

public class MyProcessor implements StringProcessor
{
  private final SomeObject someObject;

  public MyProcessor(SomeObject someObject)
  {
    this.someObject = someObject;
  }

  public void processString(String string)
  {
    // Process the string...
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  SomeObject myObject = new SomeObject();
  StringProcessor myProcessor = new MyProcessor(SomeObject myObject);
  StringProcessor asyncProcessor = new AsyncProcessor(myProcessor,100);

  asyncProcessor.processString("This string will be processed asynchronously");
}
```